# Cannot add package reference

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I'm building a xamarin.ios app in VS mac. I'm trying to add a certain package, but when I try to add it I get this error

```
jon@jons-MacBook-Pro-2 helloworld % dotnet add package Ditto                
/Users/jon/Desktop/hello-world/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.csproj(140,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.300//Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Unable to create dependency graph file for project '/Users/jon/Desktop/hello-world/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.csproj'. Cannot add package reference.
```

I have also tried using the Nuget manager and I get this when I try to build the project

```
/Users/jon/Desktop/hello-world/helloworld/helloworld/MTOUCH: Error MT0009: Error while loading assemblies: /Users/jon/.nuget/packages/ditto/1.1.8/runtimes/win/native/dittoffi.dll. (MT0009) (helloworld)
```

Any thought??

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio for Mac 2022 installed?

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes

Comment: Had you tired created a new project to test this?

Comment: I have this exact problem for Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets, too. Did you ever find a solution?